# MudBlazor dropdown not defaulting to value from database

Tags: drop-down-menu, blazor, mudblazor

I'm using Blazor with MudBlazor and I have the following form on an Edit page:

```
<EditForm Model="BookRequestVM" OnInvalidSubmit="InvalidBookRequest" OnValidSubmit="@ValidBookRequest">
    ...
    <MudItem xs="12" sm="4">
        <MudSelect T="BookType" Label="Book Type" @bind-Value="@BookRequestVM.BookType" @bind-SelectedValues="hashBookTypes" Required="true">
            @foreach (var selectItem in BookTypes)
            {
                <MudSelectItem Value="@selectItem">@selectItem.TypeTitle</MudSelectItem>
            }
        </MudSelect>
    </MudItem>
</EditForm>

...

@code {
    public class BookType
    {
        public int BookTypeId { get; set; }
        public string TypeTitle { get; set; }
    }
    
    public HashSet<BookType> hashBookTypes = new HashSet<BookType>();
    
    ...

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        BookRequestVM = await _bookService.GetBookRequest(Id);  // Fetch info from database
        
        BookTypes = _bookService.GetBookTypes().ToList();    // Get all valid dropdown values
        
        hashBookTypes = new HashSet<BookType>(BookTypes);
    }
}
```

Because I'm pulling in existing data (this Book Type field is required when creating a book request), there will always be a Book Type associated with this Book Request. I see that the BookTypeVM was able to pull the Book Type in from the database in the service call, and on the valid submit method, it's bound and gets saved properly. It's just when it loads in, it doesn't default to the value that was saved to the database--only the first value from the dropdown list. Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: Is this a multi-select?  If not then why are you setting `@bind-SelectedValues="hashBookTypes"`.  `hashBookTypes` comes from `BookTypes` which is a list of all the book types.   I'm no expert on MudBlazor, but it appears your setting the selected values to the full list of values.  Without ` MultiSelection="true"` then I'm guessing its setting the current value to the first value in the list.

Comment: You need to indicate the DOM has updated by calling `StateHasChanged()`.after setting the values in the `OnInitializedAsnyc` method.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis This was indeed the cause of the issue. I don't recall adding that bind property on my end at all until I looked closer at the code, but removing it showed the correct behavior.

Comment: Great, I added my comment as an answer for you to tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a multi-select? If not then why are you setting @bind-SelectedValues="hashBookTypes". hashBookTypes comes from BookTypes which is a list of all the book types. I'm no expert on MudBlazor, but it appears your setting the selected values to the full list of values. Without  `MultiSelection="true"` then I'm guessing its setting the current value to the first value in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has more problems than the one MrC found. You need to be very careful with using a POCO class in a select without overriding `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` because the select uses a HashSet internally to find out which item is selected. Also, if you want it to convert the selected BookType to string it should override `ToString()`.

Your BookType class should look like this:

```cs
    public class BookType
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object other) {
            return (other as BookType)?.Title == Title;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.Title.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override string ToString() => Title;
    }
```

And here is the Select to go with it:

```
    <MudSelect T="BookType" Label="Book Type" @bind-Value="@RequestedBookType" Required="true">
        @foreach (var selectItem in BookTypes)
        {
            <MudSelectItem Value="@selectItem">@selectItem.Title</MudSelectItem>
        }
    </MudSelect>
```

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates your code with above changes to make it work: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mOwvPvbhHYHFBoiV

Answer (score 0):

`@bind-SelectedValues="hashBookTypes"` was the culprit. This is used for multiselect. Unfortunately, I don't recall adding this code,  but removing this resolved this issue.